# Terminology: maps which are bi-Lipschitz on compact subsets

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, terminology, metric-spaces, lipschitz-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be such that: for every compact subset $K$ of $X$ the restricted map $f|_K:K\rightarrow Y$ defined by $f|_K(x)=f(x)$ is bi-Lipschitz (with constants depending on $K$).

*What are such functions/what is this property called?*

Comment: "If $X$ is locally compact, then this property is equivalent to $f$ being locally Lipschitz." -- This is not true If by "this property" you mean being bi-Lipschitz on compact subsets. For instance, constant functions on $\mathbb R$ are locally Lipschitz but not bi-Lipschitz on $[0,1]$. Your quoted statement is not true even for bijective functions. E.g., if $f(x)=x^3$ for real $x$, then $f$ is locally Lipschitz but not bi-Lipschitz on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis You're right.  Very nice counter example.  Still, does this relaxation of the bi-Lipschitz property have a name?

Comment: Also, I think you are using the term "etymology" incorrectly. In this context, it would mean "the origin and historical development of a certain mathematical term". But you do not have any certain term; rather, you seem to be looking for one.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Oh I didn't realize that "etymology meant that"; thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I think "locally bi-Lipschitz" would do, even though I have not encountered this term.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I was hesitant to use such as term (since if we forget about the "bi" prefix for a moment) then, to the best of my knowledge, locally-Lipschitz refers to functions on which every point has a neighbourhood on which the map in question is Lipschitz.  However, if $X$ is not locally compact then it seems that these notions differ; no?

Comment: I see. Maybe then "compactly bi-Lipschitz"; cf. "converge compactly" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20compact%20convergence%20(or,with%20the%20compact%2Dopen%20topology.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Fair enough; thanks for the helpful example and the naming (not etymology) tips :)